# What is the most correct way to define source table in \Phalcon\Mvc\Model?

Tags: model, phalcon

As i know, it is possible to define table name by following variants:

1) by defining method getSource()

```
class Table1 extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model 
{
    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'table1';
    }
}
```

2) by defining $_source property

```
protected $_source = 'table1';
```

3) Where it is necessary to define source table? in initialize() method or in __construct() and why?

4) Maybe there are other possible solutions you can tell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to define the `getSource` method in your class

```
public function getSource()
{
    return 'table1';
}
```

However you can also use the `setSource()` in the `initialize()`, or set the `$_source` in again the `initialize()` function.

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->setSource('table1');
}
```

The `initialize()` performs all the necessary work to bind the model to the database and perform other operations so that the functionality is exposed to the developer. The `__construct()` is called as one would expect upon creation of the object.

I do not think that there is a big difference on where you set the `$_source` so long as you set it properly. My personal preference is to set it in the `getSource()`. It keeps things tidy that way and I don't have to track the `$_source` variable.

Comment: It's more coding style thing. I finally left setSource($table) method in initialize(), not to define extra methods. Setting $_source variable is not very good soolution from my view, because this property is not documented :)

Comment: Describing table name in initialize() method is better because all model definitions are in the one place, it makes code more clear :)